# Show that $\langle \phi(x) - \phi(y), x-y \rangle \ge c|x-y|^2$ and $|\phi(x)- \phi(y)| \ge |x-y|$.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let  $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a function $C^1$. Suppose there is a constant $c>0$ such that $$\langle \phi'(x)h,h \rangle \ge c |h|^2, $$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that 
$$\langle \phi(x) - \phi(y), x-y \rangle \ge c|x-y|^2$$ and $$|\phi(x)- \phi(y)| \ge |x-y|$$.

*Comments*: For the second part I'm trying to use the Cauchy- Schuarz inequality.

Comment: Can you tell us what's $t$?

Comment: Sorry, is $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 0):

For the second part: your intuition about the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is correct. Try applying it to the first part and see what you get.

For the first part: if we replace the $h$ in
$$
\langle \phi'(z)h,h \rangle \geq c|h|^2
$$
with $h = x-y$, then we are very nearly where we want to be:
$$
\langle \phi'(z)(x-y),(x-y) \rangle \geq c|x-y|^2
$$
Use the definition of the derivative:
$$
\phi(z+w) - \phi(z) - \phi'(z)w = o(|w|),
$$
with $z$ and $w$ chosen carefully (namely, in terms of $x$ and $y$). This lets you write
$$
\phi(z+w) - \phi(z) - o(|w|) = \phi'(z)w.
$$
With the right choice of $z$ and $w$, you can put this inside the inner product $\langle \phi'(z)h,h\rangle$, and with an easy argument you can make the $o(|w|)$ term go away.

Comment: Chose z=y and w=x-y, but I can not see how I $o(|w|) \rightarrow 0 $ in inner product